# How do i serve 410 status code over 404 in joomla?

Tags: joomla, serve

How do i serve 410 status code over 404 in joomla? So that google will de-index my pages from serach results.

Please provide all methods in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this in the .htaccess.  Similar format to 301 redirects but only putting the URL you want to disappear.  Please note, this can still take months.

```
Redirect 410 /old-page-you-do-not-want
```

Also, make sure you are updating your robots.txt to suggest to search engines to not crawl:

```
Disallow: /old-page-you-do-not-want
```

Comment: @Yatin Arora, That is Google's recommendation although there isn't much preference to a 410 vs 404*.  For temporarily getting it to disappear, you can use the [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en) Remove URLs tool, although use it sparingly.  Those are only temporary so you need to check back frequently to see if the request has expired.    *https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2340728/matt-cutts-on-how-google-handles-404-410-status-codes

Comment: should i write like this like i wanna remove food or abour related pages so my code will be Redirect 410 /food or Redirect 410 /about is that correct..!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your original question was downvoted. In any case, please check [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/the-right-way-to-handle-404s-in-joomla) on the right way to return 404 in Joomla. Then, when implementing the post, replace the following line:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

with

```
header('HTTP/1.0 410 Gone');
```

I am not 100% sure that returning 410 instead of 404 for everything is a good idea though.

Comment: he asks for 410 probably as he received an email from Google with the following title: Increase in “soft-404” pages on http://www.example.com
In this email it is suggested to implement a solution for 404 or 410 (gone).